# Transparency in Dynamic Images (Python 3 / Tkinter)

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter with Python 3. I want to display something like this, with a particular token showing up behind an overlay:

[image: overlay]
[image: token]
[image: combined]

(This is the overlay, followed by a token, and finally the overlay over the token. The token may not always be centered though behind the overlay.)

The problem is that I need to create these images dynamically. I can't use predefined images `.png` or `.gif` images. In particular, the colors of these images are going to change frequently, and I don't know them a priori.

All of the sample code that I've seen to create images on a canvas assume that you're loading up a `.gif` or `.png`, something like this:

```
token_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="token.png")
canvas = tk.Canvas(width=500, height=500, background="black")
canvas.pack()
token = canvas.create_image((50,50), image=token_image)
```

But is there a way to do this generating the token_image dynamically? How would you create the irregular shape shown in the overlay, with the circular "bite" taken out of it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do transparency stuff in Tkinter using [BitmapImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm), but you'll need to put each color in its own "layer". OTOH, as the docs say "you can draw two-colour transparent bitmaps by associating a mask image to the bitmap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a basic example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Dynamic Image Test")

        tk.Label(self, text="Overlay").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Label(self, text="Token").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Label(self, text="Combined").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="nesw")


        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label_1.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky="nesw")
        self.label_2 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label_2.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky="nesw")
        self.label_3 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label_3.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky="nesw")

        self.images = [None, None, None]
        self.photos = [None, None, None]

        self.show_changes()

    def overlay(self):
        im = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (255,255,0,255))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        draw.ellipse((10,10,90,90),fill=(0,0,0,0))
        return im

    def token(self):
        im = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (0,0,0,0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        draw.ellipse((0,0,100,100),fill=(0,0,255,255))
        draw.line((15,15,85,85),fill=(255,0,0,255), width=5)
        draw.line((15,85,85,15),fill=(255,0,0,255), width=5)
        return im

    def combine(self, overlay, token):
        return Image.alpha_composite(token, overlay)

    def show_changes(self):
        self.images[0] = self.overlay()
        self.photos[0] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.images[0])
        self.label_1.configure(image=self.photos[0])

        self.images[1] = self.token()
        self.photos[1] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.images[1])
        self.label_2.configure(image=self.photos[1])

        self.images[2] = self.combine(self.images[0], self.images[1])
        self.photos[2] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.images[2])
        self.label_3.configure(image=self.photos[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

i was going to do a more complete example, allowing changing the colours on the fly, but i'll be honest and say i can't be bothered.

the ImageDraw module lets you do basic manipulation of images, drawing lines, rectanges ellipses etc, and also supports working in RGBA format (ie transparency)
so the colour tuples take the form (red, green, blue, alpha) where all values have a range of 0-255, with 255 meaning fully opaque in the alpha channel.

hopefully this shows you where you need to look to do what you want.